# How to save recorded file in own directory for ios?

Tags: ios, ipad, avcam

Hi I want to record video and store into local own created directory. So i follow this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Read_Me_txt.html . I can run this project successfully. But it stored into photo gallery. But i want to store into my own created directory. How can i do this? Can any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi... have you got the result ? I face the same problem...